# Android: question from hobby programmer concerning sample "Snake"

Tags: android, sample

*Thanks* if anybody will answer this (maybe?) ridiculous question:

Why is a **"public SnakeView"** in SnakeView.java defined ***TWICE*** (once *directly* after the first time!), adding the second time an arg **"int defStyle"** ?

(Both times these "publics" call **"initSnakeView"**...)

***Why*** is this necessary - what is the ***advantage***?

***THANK YOU*** very much for an *enlightenment* !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SnakeView` class sublasses `TileView`, which in turn subclasses `View`.
Those two `public SnakeView` definitions implement the two constructors that every `View` has. The first one is called when creating a `View` from code, the second one is called when it is inflated from a layout xml file. See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html).

Comment: Thank you very much - your answer is very easy to understand for me - as you explain that these two versions are meant for two different ways to create a View...

Answer (score 1):

Those are "constructors" -- a special kind of function that is called when a SnakeView object it being created. A constructor has the opportunity to set up the initial state of the object. A class can have many different constructors with different sets of objects; each one sets up the object based on whatever inputs are given. The one with no arguments is a "default" constructor, which uses default values in the absence of any input.

Comment: So if I understand this right: these two different versions of "public SnakeView" will ***both*** be called one after the other - _OR_ depending on which args are attached ***ONE*** version only will be used?

Comment: Only the one that matches the arguments will be used